# Divergence in cylindrical coordinates - Tensor Calculus way

Tags: mathematical-physics, polar-coordinates, tensors, divergence-operator

I am currently taking a course in Electrodynamics - really beautiful physics, utterly mathematical. Because of that, I am trying to have a few mathematical barriers as possible. A big focus on the course is Tensor Calculus, and one of the tasks I gave myself is to calculate the divergence of a smooth vector field in *cylindrical coordinates*.

The divergence of a vector field $\mathbf{A}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ as a tensor is defined as (at least as my professor showed):
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{A}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det{g}}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\left(\sqrt{\det{g}}\ A^i\right)$$

Where $i$ is summed from $1$ to $n$, and $g$ is the metric tensor. For example, in cartesian coordinates, since $g$ is the identity tensor we get $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{A}=\partial_iA^i$ as expected.

Now, choosing $n=3$ and the following coordinates (cylindrical):

$$\begin{align} x &= r\cos\theta\quad \hat{x}=\cos\theta\hat{r}-\sin\theta\hat\theta 
\\ y &= r\sin\theta\quad \hat{y}=\sin\theta\hat{r}+\cos\theta\hat\theta \\
z &= z\quad\quad\quad \hat{z}=\hat{z}\end{align}$$

The metric is:

$$g=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & r^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$$

Thus $\sqrt{\det{g}}=r$ and then:

$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{A}=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(rA^r)+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\color{red}{r}A^\theta)+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(A^z)$$

Which is *almost* true. I spent *a lot* of time trying to understand where is the problem, but to no avail. Something tells me it has to do with the basis covariant vectors transformation, since I didn't use it.

**Notice**: I know there are other ways (multivariable calculus ways, for instance) to derive the formula (maybe chain rule?) but I am **not** interested in them. I want to practice on the tensor-calculus-ways to do this.

**Edit**: Looking at the metric tensor, I realized that $\hat\theta\cdot\hat\theta=r^2$, therefore $\lVert\hat\theta\rVert=r$. In other words, the $\hat\theta$ basis vector is **not normalized!** Does it mean that I need divide $A^\theta$ by $r$ in order to normalize everything? I am not sure if this is the correct thought, but it if it is - then the red $r$ that shouldn't be in the divergence would cancel out and then everything is okay.

Thank you!

Comment: You are forgetting a $r$ in your computation of $\widehat{x}=\cos\theta\widehat{r}-r\sin\theta\widehat{\theta}$, and same for $\widehat{y}$.

Comment: @Balloon How is that possible? if you meant that I need to multiply the terms by $r$, then the vectors wouldn't be normalized, wouldn't they?

Comment: They would: you can't compute the cartesian norm of a vector using its cylindrical coordinates, since it is not an isometry.

Comment: @Balloon And how would that affect the divergence?

Comment: It would not, I was just pointing an error but your computation of $g$ and what follows is exact. Also, your edit is indeed the point: some conventions ask to take the coefficients in normalized basis, thus getting the formula you are looking for. It is discussed in Wikipedia there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#General_coordinates.